# Does the category of $O_X$-Modules have exact products

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, soft-question, homological-algebra, infinite-product

I was wondering if the category of $O_{X}$-Modules over a scheme $X$ has exact products. I've searched on the internet and found that it is a Grothendieck category (something that i am not familiar with but I figured that this doesn't imply the exactness of the direct products).
 Also, I would like to know, if this is not the case, whether the category of quasi-coherent $O_{X}$-Modules has exact products. Since in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215605/when-are-direct-products-exact-in-the-category-of-quasi-coherent-sheaves) it is clear that this is not always true, I claim that $X$ should be quasi-compact,quasi-separated but I can't prove anything and I am stuck. Any help or recommended reference would be very helpful.

Comment: What is an exact product?

Comment: It presumably means direct products preserve exact sequences, in other words whether $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ modules satisfy the $\text{AB4}^{*}$ axiom. The paper [Non-exactness of direct products of Quasicoherent sheaves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08752.pdf) by Ryo Kanda might be a good resource